# What does _CRTNOALIAS do

Tags: c++

I have found  _CRTNOALIAS flag in a C++ function definition in Windows enviroment. no idea what it does.
Anyone there to help

```
void _CRTNOALIAS foo()
{
}
```

Comment: never seen that before! Interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (probably) defined as

```
#define _CRTNOALIAS __declspec(noalias)
```

which will annotate functions as `noalias`.

The `noalias` annotation is a directive that helps the optimiser. It instructs the compiler that the function itself does not reference global state, but only *first-level indirections* of pointer arguments.

Consider the following:

```
int *global_bar;

void __declspec(noalias) foo (int *f) {
    int i = *f; // you can do this
    int i = f[0]; // and this

    *global_bar = *f; // YOU CAN'T DO THIS!
}
```

For more information, see the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k649tyc7(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Is this in some Visual Studio-provided header file? It looks like it may have been but in Visual Studio 2017 _CRTNOALIAS might be undefined.